# jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() with smaller list than getBatchSize() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, batch-insert

I'm calling `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()` with chunks of 1000. The list can be arbitrarily large -- and sometimes it can be less than 1000, in which case there's just that one small batch. My assumption was `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` would be smart enough to figure out how many batches to execute.

But I'm seeing the following: suppose my list has 3 items:

```
final List<UsersT> batchInsertUsers = ...; // 3 items in List

String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO USERS_T ...";

jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlInsert, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

    @Override
    public int getBatchSize() {
        return 1000; // Max Batch size greater than current list. 1 batch expected
    }

    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
        ps.setInt(1, batchInsertUsers.get(i).getId()); 
        ps.setString(2, batchInsertUsers.get(i).getPassword()); 
        // etc.
    }
```

}

Error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at app.ResearcherServiceImpl$1.setValues(ResearcherServiceImpl.java:535)
```

Answer (score 3):

`int getBatchSize()` Return the size of the batch.

Use this implementation :

```
@Override
public int getBatchSize() {
    return batchInsertUsers.size(); // Return the size of the batch.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping it would act like `MAXBatchSize` (and split up into batches itself), but you have to provide the exact number yourself. Not very smart unfortunately.